# How to hide the django AuthenticationForm built-in error_message?

Tags: python, django

I'm new to django and trying to hide the error message that has bullet on it (see screenshot below), the built-in `error_message` attribute when using the `AuthenticationForm` class on login,  because I have used the `form.errors` in the templates and wanted to keep the error message on the top. I tried to use css to hide, but when I load the login page, it wont work. Is there a way to hide or perhaps disable it? I can only see the options to customize `error_message` in the docs though.

Here is my code.

**login.html**[image]

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %} 
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}  
<!-- Custom Error Message -->
{% if  form.errors %}
    {% for _, error in form.errors.items %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger text-center">
            {{ error|striptags }}
        </div>    
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
  <div class="content-section">
      <form method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <fieldset class="form-group">
              <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Log in</legend>
              {{ form | crispy }}
          </fieldset>
          <div class="form-group">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Login</button>
              <small class="text-muted ml-2">
                  <a href="{% url 'password_reset' %}">Forgot Password?</a>
              </small>
          </div>
      </form>
      <div class="border-top pt-3">
          <small class="text-muted">
              Need An Account? <a href="{% url 'register' %}" class="ml-2">Sign Up</a>
          </small>
      </div>
  </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**forms.py**

```
class LogInAuthForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'style': 'margin:1rem 0 4rem', 'placeholder': 'Username'}))
    password = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'mb-4', 'placeholder': 'Password'}))

    error_messages = {
        'invalid_login': _("Invalid login. Note that both " "fields may be case-sensitive."),
        'inactive': _("This account is inactive."),
    }
```

**views.py**

```
class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    authentication_form = LogInAuthForm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to display the default form with errors, you can render it manually.

So replace:

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Log in</legend>
    {{ form | crispy }}
</fieldset>
```

with something like

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Log in</legend>
    {{ form.username|as_crispy_field }}
    {{ form.password|as_crispy_field }}
</fieldset>
```

Comment: it works fine to me!

Answer (score 0):

{{form|crispy}} this creates built in template form. Try inspect element on those input tags you will see form-error class or id which creates those error messages. So, may be try this (Design as you like).

````
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}  
<!-- Custom Error Message -->
{% if  form.errors %}
    {% for _, error in form.errors.items %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger text-center">
            {{ error|striptags }}
        </div>    
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
  <div class="content-section">
      <form method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <fieldset class="form-group">
              <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Log in</legend>
              <input class="form-class" name="username" placeholder="Username">
             <input class="form-class" name="password" placeholder="Password">
          </fieldset>
          <div class="form-group">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Login</button>
              <small class="text-muted ml-2">
                  <a href="{% url 'password_reset' %}">Forgot Password?</a>
              </small>
          </div>
      </form>
      <div class="border-top pt-3">
          <small class="text-muted">
              Need An Account? <a href="{% url 'register' %}" class="ml-2">Sign Up</a>
          </small>
      </div>
  </div>
{% endblock content %}```
````